# A basic logical question on on sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n:[0,\infty)$ and $f:[0,\infty)$ be a sequence of functions such that for every finite $T$,   $f_n:[0,T]\rightarrow f:[0,T]$ uniformly. But,  it need not be true that $f_n:[0,\infty)\rightarrow f:[0,\infty)$ uniformly. In one book I have seen that the above is true is "assumed". Is this a correct practice ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly. It is true that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each $[0,T]$, then $f_n$ does not have to converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. For example, let $f_n(x):=0$ for $x\leq n$ and $f_n(x):=1$ elsewhere. Then for fixed $T$ we have that $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,T]$ for all $n\geq T$, so $f_n$ converges uniformly to 0 on $[0,T]$. However, $f_n$ converges not uniformly to 0 on $[0,\infty)$, because $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-0|=1$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Thus, if you want to have uniform convergence on all of $[0,\infty)$, you have to add additional assumptions.

Comment: The book "assumes" that it is uniformly convergent on the whole interval if and only if the property holds for all finite interval. Actually he defines relative compactness of a collection $A$ on $C[0,\infty)$ if the collection is relatively compact on $C[0,T]$ for every finite $T$. This is my confusion. Is it a correct thing to do ?

Comment: Yes, of course. With this assumption he guarantees that examples like I used here cannot occur. So all functions must behave "nice" for large $x$. Maybe you can write down the theorem you are relating to?

Comment: OK. understood.